# SharePoint 2016 suite bar - Color Palette Tool seems to mess with its colour

Tags: theme

I have created a spcolor file with the Color Palette tool, but it seems that the tool somehow messes up with the colour of the Suit Bar at the top. I want the bar to be black like the default, but somehow the bar keeps getting blue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the Palette001.spcolor. This palette is the default one in SharePoint 2016 and it clearly shows the bar as black.
2. Open the file with the Colour Palette tool and simply save it with another name. No need to make a single alteration. For example, save it as PAlette000.spcolor so it shows as the first option when changing the look of a theme.
3. Upload the saved file to the Themes/15 folder of the site collection.
4. Try changing the look of a site and try applying this colour palette.

One can clearly see that while the Palette001 gives us a black suite bar, the copy we just made -- without ANY alteration -- gives us a blue suite bar.

Of course I also tried explicitly changing the value of the "Suite Bar Background" entry (found under "Bucket - 03" in the Color Palette Tool) -- but that is also ignored.

Any ideas how we can change the value of the Suite Bar in SharePoint 2016 by using an spcolor file -- and NOT by modifying any CSS?

Comment: OK something funny is going on. I did a search around the interwebs for a while before posting this question and I could see others experiencing the same or similar issues. After trying for the 10th-or-so time, I got it working (?!) by just changing the Suite Bar Background colour in the Color Palette Tool. Something is not right... Can anyone reproduce the same issue?

Comment: I was able to repro.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSeward. Clearly there is a "bug" in the tool. Or to be more specific, it needs an update to better work with SP2016. Funny thing is that I got it to work after several trial and errors -- but I did nothing different than what I outlined above.

Comment: We have similar bug in our environment (16.0.4456.1000).
For us the Suite Bar turns to 'blue' once we add a background image via SP UI. Not even using the Color Palette Tool.
Did anyone find a permanent fix?